# C# get distinct values from jagged array

Tags: c#, jagged-arrays

I'm looking for a way to get distinct values from a jagged array.  I've tried putting it in a dictionary, but it doesn't seem to see the values as distinct.  Anyone any ideas for a solution?  Here is what I have so far:

```
int[][] connectionList = GetArray();
```

Sample data returned from this:

```
[0][1, 130, 136, 138]
[1][1, 78, 126, 138]
[2][1, 10, 125, 138]
[3][1, 130, 136, 138]
[4][1, 78, 126, 138]
[5][1, 130, 136, 138]
[6][1, 72, 135, 138]
[7][1, 73, 135, 138]
[8][1, 130, 136, 138]
```

Have tried adding to a dictionary.  I tried to catch duplicate values as they are added, but that didn't work, so tried to add .Distinct(), but no joy there either

```
Dictionary<int, int[]> myDictionary = new Dictionary<int, int[]>();
for (int i = 0; i < connectionList.Length; i++)
{ 
    List<int> list = new List<int>();
    for (int j = 0; j < connectionList[i].Length; j++)
    {
        list.Add(connectionList[i][j]);        
    }
    if (myDictionary.Where(x => x.Value == list.ToArray()).Count() == 0)
        myDictionary.Add(i, list.ToArray());
}
var distinctList = myDictionary.Values.Distinct().ToList();
```

From the above list, the output I'm looking for would be:

```
[0][1, 130, 136, 138]
[1][1, 78, 126, 138]
[2][1, 10, 125, 138]
[4][1, 72, 135, 138]
[5][1, 73, 135, 138]
```

Any thoughts how I could achieve this?

Comment: Is it supposed to be unique per key or globally?

Comment: It's only the values that need to be unique - key not important.

Comment: Can't think how else I would write it Yuriy. How might you write an int[][]?

Comment: *its only the keys that need to be unique- value can be anything including null- and can be associated with multiple keys

Comment: in your first example, would connectionList[1,2]=126? Just an interesting way of writing it.

Comment: have you tried to enter the input of the array as a one string? 
like: [0]["1, 130, 136, 138"] will be in one string instead of adding 4 elements it will be only one. then when you want to extract the data you just use split function or something to get the values out.

Comment: @RobinVanPersi: Couldn't you at least suggest using `System.Net.IPAddress` (as it seems to be exactly that) rather than a `string`?

Comment: @Tobias - potato potatoe... it doesn't make any difference..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

```
var distinctList = connectionList.GroupBy(x => string.Join(",", x))
                                 .Select(g => g.First())
                                 .ToList();
```

Although it's probably preferable to create a custom [`IEqualityComparer<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151.aspx) -- as suggested by [Crab Bucket](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9067250/55847) and [Tobias](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9067256/55847) -- rather than creating a throwaway string to use for the comparison.

Comment: @dario_ramos look at his full question, he obviously knows LINQ.

Comment: Hi Luke - I think you're right that the EqualityComparer would probably be the best solution, but this does work well enough, so I'll just stick to this.  Cheers

Answer (score 2):

This will be easy with a LINQ `Distinct`, all you need is to provide your own implementation for `IEqualityComparer`:

```
public class IntArrayComparer : IEqualityComparer<int[]>
{
    public bool Equals(int[] i1, int[] i2)
    {
        if(ReferenceEquals(i1, i2))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else if(i1 == null || i2 == null)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else if(i1.Length != i2.Length)
        {
            return false;
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < i1.Length; ++i)
        {
            if(i1[i] != i2[i]) return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(int[] obj)
    {
        // Average is probably not the best hash for an int array,
        // but I'm lazy right now and this is only for demonstration purposes
        return obj != null ? (int)obj.Average() : 0;
    }
}
```

And use it in your code, like this:

```
int[][] connectionList = GetArray().Distinct(new IntArrayComparer()).ToArray();
```

Comment: Thanks Tobias - this looks interesting. Not sure I understand it 100% just now so I'll go and look into it further - when I implemented as shown above, it returns an empty array so I'll play about with it and report back.  Thanks very much

Answer (score 1):

Could you user IEqualityComparer

```
 public class MyComparer : IEqualityComparer<int []> 
    {     
        bool IEqualityComparer<int[]>.Equals(int[] x, int[] y)     
        {         
             //.. your particular comparison logic goes here
        }
        int IEqualityComparer<int[]>.GetHashCode(int [] obj)     
        {         
            return obj.GetHashCode();     
        }     

    }
```

Then call like this

```
var distinctList = myDictionary.Values.Distinct(new MyComparer()).ToList();
```